# Find $x$ such that $\frac{x-{{a}^{2}}}{b+c}+\frac{x-{{b}^{2}}}{c+a}+\frac{x-{{c}^{2}}}{a+b}=4\left( a+b+c \right)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $$\frac{x-{{a}^{2}}}{b+c}+\frac{x-{{b}^{2}}}{c+a}+\frac{x-{{c}^{2}}}{a+b}=4\left( a+b+c \right),$$ 
find the value of $x$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$

tried ample of times but could get it.
A hint is sufficient

Comment: Clear the denominators on the LHS; and add the terms to get a 'standard' $mx+n=p$ linear form. Once you get the _complicated_ formula for $x$ you can think about simplifying it.

Comment: x=(a+b+c)^2. but cant reach near to the solution

Comment: @StevenStadnicki

Comment: i think it is not so simple since we have $$a,b,c$$ as parameters

Answer (score 1):

HINT: moving all Terms to the left and factorizing we obtain:
$$-\frac{\left(a^2+3 a b+3 a c+b^2+3 b c+c^2\right) \left(a^2+2 a b+2 a c+b^2+2 b
   c+c^2-x\right)}{(a+b) (a+c) (b+c)}=0$$
can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A kinda brute force solution. First multiply both sides by $(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$,

$$ (c+a)(a+b)(x-a^2) + (b+c)(a+b)(x-b^2) + (c+a)(b+c)(x-c^2) = 4(a+b+c)(b+c)(c+a)(a+b) $$

Now multiply out each term and combine factors of $x$ to get,

$$ (3ac + 3bc + 3ab + a^2 + b^2 + c^2)x - (a^3c + a^2bc + a^3 + a^3b + ab^3 + b^3 + ab^2c + b^3c + bc^3 + c^3 + abc^2 + ac^3) = 4(a+b+c)(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) $$

Now this is of the form $p=qx+c$ and can be simplified to $x = \frac{p-c}{q}$, which will be ugly, but correct nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

It's a linear equation and for $x=(a+b+c)^2$ we have an identity.

Indeed, for $x=(a+b+c)^2$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x-a^2}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b+c)^2-a^2}{b+c}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(b+c)(2a+b+c)}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}(2a+b+c)=4(a+b+c).$$
Thus, $(a+b+c)^2$ is our unique root.

Done!